# Every template from moderator private message has lost the translation

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, moderator-messages

All moderator message templates have lost their translations.

For instance, the translation for the template ["question repetition"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16845) was made a long time ago and was available before the mod private message redesign.

> [image]

Comment: facepalm! no, not again... and where are the CM that usually told us that things like this happens??? ah... they were all layd off... you are making the mods works harder than ever.... :(

Comment: @gbianchi again? If this bug happened in the past, worth adding this to the bug report and link to the previous bug report. Also, mods can't fix that, and probably not even CM, only developers. They also got a hit, but from what I've seen so far, looks like less fatal i.e. many are still working for SE.

Comment: Well that's ... fun. Nothing changed for the templates themselves that I'm aware of. We did make some changes to how translations are processed as part of deployment, but I'd expect issues with that to break more broadly than just for these strings. I'm looking into it, will update soon as I have something.

Comment: @AdamLear: Judging from the screenshot, I'm guessing something broke/changed with the spacing in the mod message template (e.g. spaces being changed to line break, or one type of spacing changing to another) - see the line break between "first thing to do" and "is to improve the question".

Comment: @V2Blast The strings generally haven't changed (the weird line break is still there in v1 templates), but... we moved to storing translations in a Github repo and, uh, now line endings vary between LF and CRLF depending on the OS of the system where they're checked out. ‍♂️ Working on a fix for that with m0sa. I'll follow up on the linebreak for this template after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. [As I said in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394462/every-template-from-moderator-private-message-has-lost-the-translation?noredirect=1#comment1318938_394462), the tl;dr here is that we had an issue with line endings in the template strings (and any multi-line strings in general), which broke our translation lookups.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the report!